# Переменные-ссылки в Python

Tags: python, указатели, ссылки

Я так понял, что все переменные в Python - это ссылки, которые ссылаются на один объект, а не на участок памяти как в С/C++.

А есть ли возможность создания ссылки на один участок памяти, чтобы изменялось значение при работе с любой из ссылок?

Например (условно),

```
a = 10
b = &a
print(a, b)  # 10 10
b = 20
print(a, b)  # 20 20
a = 15
print(a, b)  # 15 15
```

Мне это нужно, чтобы сокращать запись для доступа ко внутренним значениям вложенных словарей:

```
username   = "test"
userdata   = [10, 2, 30, 15]
user       = {username:userdata}

serveraddr = "127.0.0.1"
server     = {serveraddr:user}

# хочется создать имена-сокращения для этих элементов    
joincount  = server[serveraddr][username][0]
leftcount  = server[serveraddr][username][1]
gamescount = server[serveraddr][username][2]
wincount   = server[serveraddr][username][3]

# пробуем изменить их значения
joincount  = 20
leftcount  = 9
gamescount = 10
wincount   = 3

# проверяем, что значения в словаре остались прежними
print(server[serveraddr][username][0], server[serveraddr][username][1],
      server[serveraddr][username][2], server[serveraddr][username][3])
# (10, 2, 30, 15)

# хотя значения переменных изменились
print joincount, leftcount, gamescount, wincount
# (20, 9, 10, 3)
```

В коде очень часто используются конструкции вида `server[serveraddr][username][n]`, большая их часть приходится на места где все индексы вычислены. Поэтому хотелось бы вместо `server[serveraddr][username][0]` использовать `joincount` - это улучшило бы читаемость кода.

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: «Не для экономии памяти же?» — Для безопасности же. По идее питон не может упасть от ошибок сегментации или стать уязвимым от переполнения буферов. И да, ссылки по определению работают точно так же, как в C++ (не надо путать ссылки с указателями).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

В Python есть изменяемые и неизменяемые типы. Изменяемые отличаются тем, что их содержимое можно сменить, не изменив ссылку на них. Неизменяемые объекты приходится пересоздавать, чтобы отразить изменения состояния. При этом все старые ссылки не видят это обновление, потому что указывают на старый объект.

Поясню на практике. Списки, словари, множества - это изменяемые объекты:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1
print(l1, l2, id(l1), id(l2))  
# [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] 139917408901064 139917408901064

l1[1] = 10
print(l1, l2, id(l1), id(l2))  
# [1, 10, 3] [1, 10, 3] 139917408901064 139917408901064
```

Числа, строки, кортежи - это неизменяемые объекты:

```
v1 = 1024
v2 = v1
print(v1, v2, id(v1), id(v2))
# 1024 1024 ...7040 ...7040

v1 = 2048
print(v1, v2, id(v1), id(v2))
# 2048 1024 ...5312 ...7040

t1 = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = t1
print(t1, t2, id(t1), id(t2))
# (1, 2, 3) (1, 2, 3) ...6232 ...6232

# t1[1] = 10  # не сработает, так как кортежи неизменяемые
t1 = (1, 10, 3)
print(t1, t2, id(t1), id(t2))
# (1, 10, 3) (1, 2, 3) ...7240 ...6232
```

В своём коде вы используете изменяемые структуры данных, такие как словари и списки (`user`, `userdata`, `server`) и неизменяемые строки и числа.

Таким образом, ничего не изменяя в структуре хранения информации, максимально можно сократить только доступ до списка чисел

```
my_userdata = server[serveraddr][username]

# изменение my_userdata влечёт изменение server[serveraddr][username],
#    так как это один и тот же объект
```

Так как числа неизменяемые, то сохранение их в переменную и дальнейшее изменение этой переменной никак не сказываются на исходном числе (т.е. переменная `joincount` никогда не изменится при изменении `server[serveraddr][username][0]`, и наоборот). изменение чисел в этом списке никак не отразится на переменных, хранящих эти значения

---

Но если попробовать немного улучшить код, то стоит создать класс `UserData`, который будет хранить в себе нужные значения и позволять их изменять. Минимальный пример будет следующий:

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(self, joincount, leftcount, gamescount, wincount):
        self.joincount = joincount
        self.leftcount = leftcount
        self.gamescount = gamescount
        self.wincount = wincount

username   = "test"
userdata   = UserData(10, 2, 30, 15)
user       = {username:userdata}
```

После этого, если мы получаем откуда-то нашего пользователя, мы можем изменить нужные значения:

```
user_data = server[serveraddr][username]

user_data.joincount  = 20
user_data.leftcount  = 9
user_data.gamescount = 10
user_data.wincount   = 3

print (server[serveraddr][username].joincount, 
       server[serveraddr][username].leftcount,
       server[serveraddr][username].gamescount, 
       server[serveraddr][username].wincount)

print (user_data.joincount, user_data.leftcount, 
       user_data.gamescount, user_data.wincount)
```

Использование подобной структуры увеличит читаемость вашего кода, по сравнению с использованием индексов списка.

---

Если есть доступ на изменение содержимого словаря, я бы рекомендовал вам вместо самописного класса использовать `namedtuple` из стандартного модуля `collections`, который позволяет создавать объект, по поведению схожий с кортежем, но предоставляющий доступ к полям, как у класса выше (но только на чтение):

```
UserData = collections.namedtuple('UserData', 
    ['joincount', 'leftcount', 'gamescount', 'wincount'])
```

В этом случае придётся *заменять* старый объект `UserData` новым:

```
old_userdata = server[serveraddr][username]
new_userdata = UserData(joincount=20, leftcount=9, gamescount=10, wincount=3)

server[serveraddr][username] = new_userdata
print(new_userdata, old_userdata, server[serveraddr][username])
```

Получение поля на чтение будет выполняться так же, как и в примере выше:

```
print(old_userdata.joincount, old_userdata.gamescount)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Развернуто и доходчиво.

Comment: Поэтому очень важно подробно описывать свой вопрос. Удачи вам с изучением Python!

Answer (score 9):

Вам нужно прочитать и разобраться с mutable и immutable объектами в python.
Да вы можете делать ссылку на вложенный список, и заполнять его через нее.
Например:

```
lst = [[]]
sublst = lst[0]
sublst.append(1)
print(lst)
sublst.append(2)
print(lst)
print(id(lst[0]))
print(id(sublst))
sublst[0] = -1
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1]]
[[1, 2]]
139794716732424
139794716732424
[[-1, 2]]
```

В данном случае `sublst` это ссылка на вложенный список в `lst`, вызов `sublst.append` равнозначен `lst[0].append`. Аналогично вы можете работать например со словарем.

Comment: то есть, если я хочу изменить значение элемента, то мне нужно сначала удалить его?

Comment: Нет, вы можете написать например так: sublst[0] = -1. И значение поменяется в списке lst.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с подобным вопросом: хотелось бы иметь список ссылок на переменные.

Делаю сканер сети.
В моем случае сейчас два файла - логика и GUI, которая ее использует.
В логике постоянно меняются счетчики/флаги/данные последних вычислений... - все это в виде атрибутов класса в разных потоках.

В GUI сейчас хочу все эти данные вывести с периодическим обновлением в отдельный фрейм.
Самый "тупой" вариант - все прописать в GUI по прямым именам. Я уже привык передавать ссылки на методы и не понимаю этот двойной стандарт: "ссылки на методы можно, а на атрибуты нельзя!"

НО пока писал - понял решение, которое не видел по неопытности:

1. создаю функцию в классе логики, выдающую словарь
2. словарь заполняю актуальными данными
3. из GUI вызываю этот метод и прохожусь по значениям, выводя все во фрейм

таким образом я не думаю, что там есть внутри, достаточно настроить формирование в логике