# Почему инкапсулированные в класс атрибуты можно изменять?

Tags: python, классы

Допустим, имеется вот такой код

```
class Test:
    __atribute = None

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.__atribute = arg

    def get_atrib(self):
        return self.__atribute


test = Test([52])

var = test.get_atrib()
var[0] = 100

print(test.get_atrib())
```

Вывод будет "[100]". Вопрос - почему? Ведь атрибут был сделан приватным(двойное подчеркивание).

Comment: не пишу на питоне, и плохо знаю синтасксис, но ведь вы его нигде снаружи не видите как я вижу, да вы его изменяете после получения, и это правильное изменение, но его самого вы не видите

Comment: @AiSatan
оно-то да. но я изменяю переменную, в которую загнал атрибут(вернее поле)и при этом изменяется и само поле. снаружи я не должен его мочь изменить, а только с помощью какого-нибудь метода класса. сеттера, например.

Comment: Вы передаете массив по ссылке, т.е. вы здесь меняете не `self.__atribute`, а массив, на который он указывает. Попробуйте сделать то же самое для числа - увидите, что оно не меняется.

Comment: @BOPOH ок, понял спасибо. но что делать? использовать copy.deepcopy()?

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезен и этот [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420140/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python/420327)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как объяснили в комментариях, все что делает добавление `__` в начало названия атрибута класса - это усложняет ([даже не запрещает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private)) доступ к атрибуту извне:

```
>>> class Test():
...   __attr = 1
...   def __init__(self, val):
...     self.__attr = val
...   def get_val(self):
...     return self.__attr
...
>>> test = Test(5)
>>> test.get_val()
5
>>> test.__attr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute '__attr'
>>> test._Test__attr
5
```

`__` не делает сам объект, на который ссылается этот атрибут неизменяемым, поэтому когда вы возвращаете [ссылку](http://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-copy.html) на объект вовне - объект можно изменить, используя эту ссылку.

Что с этим делать - зависит от вашего конкретного случая.

- Можно как вы сами предложили делать `copy.deepcopy()` - надо понимать, что тогда при каждом вызове getter'а будет происходить копирование, даже если вызывающий ничего не собирался менять в полученном объекте.
- Можно возвращать `tuple(self.__mylist)`, вот тут подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/a/23474802/1026
- Можно возвращать объект-обертку вокруг вашего списка, который не позволяет его менять
- Можно возвращать конкретные элементы списка по запросу (если вызывающий код заинтересован только в определенной части списка).