# Перевод списка строк в список чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

`a` - список строк :`['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']`

```
for el in a:
    el = int(el)
```

пытался таким способом преобразовать в числа, но в преобразует в рамках данного цикла

Comment: Во многих языках когда используется цикл вида for-in элементы оисходной последовательности являются неизменяемыми. То есть вы имеете дело с копиями элементов. Я не знаю Python, но, думаю, здесь имеет место тоже самое.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезен [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420140/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python/420327#420327)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Наиболее идиоматический и идеологически выверенный способ:

```
result = [int(item) for item in a]
```

Для любителей функционального стиля:

```
result = list(map(int, a))
```

Тут функция `map` применяет функцию `int` к каждому элементу объекта `a`, потом результат преобразовывается в список.

Такой вариант считается менее "питоничным", но тоже имеет право на существование (как минимум, во многих случаях запись через `map` получается более компактной, чем вариант через списочное выражение).

---

По поводу вашего первого варианта: когда вы пишете `for el in a`, то каждый раз в цикле в `el` записывается ссылка на элемент списка. Но когда вы пишете `el = int(el)`, то в переменную `el` просто записывается другая ссылка, сам элемент списка не меняется.

Как понять, что это именно ссылка, а не копия элемента? Вот пример, как при помощи вызова метода элемента списка меняется сам элемент:

```
>>> a = [[], [], []]
>>> for el in a:
        el.append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

По поводу вашего ответа, перебор со счетчиком (если он вам вдруг действительно понадобится) на Python правильнее (проще и приятнее, без всяких len вложенных в range) делать через enumerate:

```
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = int(item)
```

Answer (score 21):

Различные способы выполнить это преобразование:

1. Изменяя непосредственно элементы массива

   ```
   for i, elem in enumerate(array):
       array[i] = int(elem)
   ```
2. Создавая новый массив вместо старого

   ```
   array = [int(elem) for elem in array]
   ```

   или

   ```
   array = list(map(int, array))
   ```

---

Вот более подробное объяснение происходящего:

Для начала вспомним, что все переменные в Python являются ссылками на объекты.

Пусть у нас будет массив `array` со следующим содержимым:

```
array = ['10', '11', '12']
```

Вот как это будет представляться в памяти в Python (`idN` -- это адрес объекта в памяти):

[image: визуализация массива]

Заметьте, что строки не хранятся напрямую в списке, они хранятся снаружи, а в списке есть указатели на них.

---

Когда вы перебираете значения в цикле, например,

```
for elem in array:
    elem = int(elem)
```

На каждой итерации переменная `elem` просто будет указывать на текущее число массива `array`.

Например, на первой итерации:

[image: elem указывает на первую строку]

Если мы попробуем присвоить что-то переменной `elem`, то мы просто заменим то, на что она будет указывать на текущей итерации цикла:

[image: elem указывает на новый объект]

Заметьте, что в массиве при этом ссылка не меняется, и нулевой элемент как указывал на строку `"10"`, так и продолжает на неё указывать:

[image: array[0] указывает всё ещё на старый объект]

Т.е. наша задача на самом деле заключается в том, чтобы *заменить ссылку, хранящуюся в списке `array` на новую*, т.е. в нашей визуализации на `id5`.

---

Чтобы это сделать, нам нужно получить доступ *на запись* в конкретную ячейку списка. Список позволяет сделать это через доступ по индексу. Напишем следующий код (подобный которому как раз используется вами в собственном ответе):

```
array = ['10', '11', '12']
for i in range(len(array)):
    old_value = array[i]
    new_value = int(old_value) 
    array[i] = new_value
```

Я расписал в несколько строк для наглядности.

Здесь на первой итерации цикла мы получаем переменную `i`, хранящую не ссылку на строку, а позицию в списке `array`, в которой нам нужно заменить ссылку:

[image: переменная i хранит число 0, а не ссылку на строку "10"]

Далее получаем строку, хранящуюся по этому индексу для того, чтобы преобразовать её в число (здесь она сохраняется в отдельной переменной, в вашем коде это будет временный объект):

```
old_value = array[i]
```

[image: old_value указывает на строку в списке]

Имея значение элемента, мы можем выполнить над ним интересующую нас операцию. Снова сохраним его в отдельной переменной.

```
new_value = int(old_value)
```

[image: new_value указывает на полученное число]

Имея новое значение и индекс, по которому его нужно сохранить в нашем списке, у нас не остаётся проблем, чтобы завершить выполнение итерации, сохранив новое значение в нужном месте:

```
array[i] = new_value
```

[image: изменили первое значение в списке]

Таким образом и производится изменение значений массива.

Приведу для сравнения краткую запись этого кода:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = int(array[i])
```

Важно понимать, что на самом деле количество операций в этом варианте и в более полном варианте будет примерно одинаковое (за вычетом создания лишних переменных).

---

Если скомбинировать оба этих способа, можно получить немного более удобную запись этого же преобразования:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = int(elem)
```

Функция [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) для нашего списка вернёт последовательность вида

```
[(0, '10'), (1, '11'), (2, '12')]
```

Такой цикл избавляет нас от необходимости писать самостоятельно доступ по индексу массива. Важно понимать, что переменная `elem` и здесь не даёт нам доступа на запись в массив, она просто хранит указатель на объект, хранящийся по текущему индексу в списке.

---

Эти способы имеют смысл, если нам важно изменять именно элементы списка. Например, если у нас есть больше одной переменной, хранящей этот список, и нам нужно сделать так, чтобы во всех переменных при доступе по индексу мы после преобразования получали целые числа вместо строк.

Такие ситуации встречаются, например, когда мы пишем функцию, которая должна изменить значения в переданном списке вместо создания нового.

---

Если же нам не требуется изменять этот список, а достаточно создания нового, в котором будут храниться целочисленные представления соответствущих элементов, то можно воспользоваться встроенной функцией [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), как предложил [@ReinRaus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus):

```
array = list(map(int, array))
```

Только стоит помнить, что в Python 3 функция `map` возвращает генератор, поэтому стоит явно преобразовать результат в список.

Ещё один удобный способ получения такого же результата, это использование генератора списков:

```
array = [int(elem) for elem in array]
```

Оба этих решения эквивалентны и являются аналогом следующего кода:

```
result_array = []
for elem in array:
    result_array.append(int(elem))
array = result_array
```

Эти решения оставляют исходный список неизменным, создавая новый и только после присваивая его переменной `array`.

---

Продемострирую разницу этих способов на примере:

```
array = ['10', '11', '12']
link = array
```

Важно понимать, что здесь обе переменные будут указывать на один и тот же список, а не являться двумя списками с одинаковыми значениями (здесь все ссылки явно отрисованы стрелками):

[image: обе переменных указывают в одно и то же место]

Выполним преобразование, изменяя элементы списка:

```
array = ['10', '11', '12']
link = array
print(array, link)    # ['10', '11', '12'] ['10', '11', '12']
for i, elem in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = int(elem)
print(array, link)    # [10, 11, 12] [10, 11, 12]
```

Как мы видим, массив непосредственно изменился, а вместе с ним изменились данные, которые доступны по переменным, указывающим на этот список:

[image: изменились значения элементов списка]

Если же воспользоваться вторым способом

```
array = ['10', '11', '12']
link = array
print(array, link)    # ['10', '11', '12'] ['10', '11', '12']
array = list(map(int, array))
print(array, link)    # [10, 11, 12] ['10', '11', '12']
```

то ещё по выводу программы можно заметить, что содержимое исходного списка не изменилось. Итоговая картина объектов будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы видим, что был создан новый список, в котором были сохранены числовые представления значений исходного.

---

Для визуализации использовался сервис [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Все намного проще:

```
result = map( int, arr )
```

Comment: Только `map` в Python 3 возвращает генератор, поэтому стоит преобразовать явно в `list`

Answer (score 2):

еще так можно

```
a = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']

[*array] = map(int, a)
print(array)

a1, *array = map(int, a)
print([a1] + array)
```

Comment: В 3 питоне такое не сработает, потому что функция map создаёт генератор

Comment: неверное утверждение, просто попробуйте, дело тут не в `map`, а в распаковке `*`

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
            a[i] = int(a[i])
            print(type(a[i]))
```

решил посредством перебора по счетчику