# Список получился не так как нужно. Почему?

Tags: python, list

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ll = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] % 2 == 0:
        l[i] = 0
        ll.append(l)
print(ll)

>>> [[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0]]
```

Почему так вышло я не понимаю?

Я ожидал `[[1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что все ячейки списка ll ссылаются на один список l, который вы изменяете. Попробуем проверить этим кодом:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ll = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] % 2 == 0:
        l[i] = 0
        ll.append(l)
        print(ll)
```

Вот что будет на выходе:

```
>> [[1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
>> [[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6]]
>> [[1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0]]
```

Более подробно можете прочитать в ответе на этот вопрос: [Переменные-ссылки в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420140/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python)

Для того, чтобы добавить в список копию списка, а не ссылку на список вы можете воспользоваться функцией list() или методом copy():

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ll = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] % 2 == 0:
        l[i] = 0
        ll.append(list(l)) # можно использовать ll.append(l.copy())
print(ll)
>> [[1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0]]
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, как исправить поведение. Вызовом `list`, например.

Answer (score 3):

Решается просто, добавлением `[:]`:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ll = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] % 2 == 0:
        l[i] = 0
        ll.append(l[:])
print(ll)
```

Comment: Ну так вы объясните товарищу, что такое `[:]`, и почему результат получается другой.

Comment: @strawdog, в ответе выше объяснили.

Comment: Тогда ваш ответ бесполезен, я так понимаю?

Comment: @strawdog, ответ выше не решает проблему.

Comment: Так ответ выше все объясняет или не решает проблему. Если автор вопроса не понимает базовых вещей, нужно ему их объяснить, а не давать "магическое заклинание".

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @strawdog, автор вопроса возможно понимает больше чем вы думаете, если сам не задает дополнительные вопросы.